# Wix Burn: Unsetting variable upon failed registry search

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

In my Bundle project, I'm searching registry for a version and setting a variable:

```
<Variable Name="Installed_Ver" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="version" Value="0.0.0.0" Persisted="yes" />

<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="Self_Ver"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="Software\MyCompany\MyProductName"
  Value="Version"
  Variable="Installed_Ver"  
  Format="raw"
  Win64="yes"
```

/>

And using this in Condition as:

```
<util:RegistrySearchRef Id="Self_Ver"  />
<bal:Condition Message="A recent or same version of this product is already installed on this machine. Please contact product support for more information." >
  <![CDATA[WixBundleInstalled OR (WixBundleFileVersion > Installed_Ver)]]>
</bal:Condition>
```

This works fine if HKLM\Software\MyCompany\MyProductName\Version exists. But if this registry doesn't exist then registry search would fail and it is  Unsetting the variable 'Installed_Ver'. This causes the condition wrongly evaluating to false.

By defining , I tried to set a default value i.e. "0.0.0.0" so it should have some value and condition would be evaluated properly i.e. to True in this case.

Here is the log, which shows that it is Unsetting the variable 'Installed_Ver'.

> [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'RegVersionCheck'
>   [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Testing'
>   [5898:3354][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
>   [5898:3354][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '7.1.2.3'
>   [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i100: Detect begin, 1 packages
>   [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\MyCompany\MyProductName'
>   [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i000: ***Unsetting variable 'Installed_Ver'***
>   [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i101: Detected package: MainProduct, state: Absent, cached: None
>   [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i104: Detected package: MainProduct, feature: CalculatorFeature, state: Absent
>   [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i052: Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR (WixBundleFileVersion > Installed_Ver)' evaluates to false.
>   [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]e000: A recent or same version of this product is already installed on this machine. Please contact product support for more information.
>   [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]e000: Error 0x81f40001: Bundle condition evaluated to false: WixBundleInstalled OR (WixBundleFileVersion > Installed_Ver)
>   [5898:2AC4][2018-08-30T13:15:08]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0

I tried by hard-coding "0.0.0.0" in the condition in place of Installed_Ver and it works fine.

**How should I get a default value for Installed_Ver if registry search fails?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching, I've found a little workaround so that I can use the default value (0.0.0.0) being setup in the Variable definition. I defined another search for same registry key and getting the Boolean (exist) variable and depending upon this variable deciding to trigger the original search and get the version value. Here is my solution:

```
<Fragment Id="Self_Install_Check">

<?define ProdRegKey=Software\MyCompany\MyProductName?>
<Variable Name="Installed_Ver" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="version" Value="0.0.0.0" Persisted="yes" />

<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="Self_Ver"
  After="ProdRegExist"
  Condition="ProdRegKeyExist"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="$(var.ProdRegKey)"
  Value="Version"
  Variable="Installed_Ver"
  Format="raw"
  Win64="yes"
/>

<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="ProdRegExist"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="$(var.ProdRegKey)"
  Value="Version"
  Variable="ProdRegKeyExist"
  Result="exists"
  Format="raw"
  Win64="yes"
/>
</Fragment>
```

So now the registry search for reading version would only be triggered if ProdRegKeyExist becomes true and Installed_Ver won't be Unset while retaining value=0.0.0.0 or else would get the Version value from registry...

Answer (score 2):

This is an [open bug](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5355). You should be able to work around this by updating your condition to handle when the Variable is not defined.

```
WixBundleInstalled OR ((WixBundleFileVersion > Installed_Ver) AND Installed_Ver)
```

Comment: Looks like the bug was fixed in Wix 4.0 in 11/2020